# issues installiing easyAdmin

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I am trying to install EasyAdminBundle on symfony 4.1 and i get the error below. i have tried with " composer require easycorp/easyadmin-bundle" but i still get the same error
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for easycorp/easyadmin-bundle ^2.3 -> satisfiable by easycorp/easyadmin-bundle[v2.3.0].
    - easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v2.3.0 requires symfony/asset ^4.2 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Comment: And what's the problem with the given message? Have you read it properly? Which **exact** line are you using to require the package?

Comment: i used  the command - composer require admin and secondly "composer require easycorp/easyadmin-bundle"

Comment: this is the error i get Problem 1 - Installation request for easycorp/easyadmin-bundle ^2.3 -> satisfiable by easycorp/easyadmin-bundle[v2.3.0]. - easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v2.3.0 requires symfony/asset ^4.2 -> no matching package found.

Comment: i think i have solved the issue, i have used the command  "composer require javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle"  and it  has worked

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed symfony/asset ?
`composer require symfony/asset`.
Follow the indications in the message. Then you do : `composer require admin` to intall [EasyAdmin](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/installation.html)